# In GWT I get could not get type signature for class Exception

Tags: java, gwt

I define a class with Generic type like below in GWT. when I extend this class with a type or specify a type for this class everything is okay, but at runtime I get "could not get type signature for class Filter" message.

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Filter<T extends Serializable> implements Serializable {
     private FilterInfo<T> info;
     private T value;

     public Filter() { }

     public FilterInfo<T> getInfo() {return info;}
     public void setInfo(FilterInfo<T> info) { this.info = info; }
     public T getValue() { return value; }
     public void setValue(T value) {this.value = value;}
}
```

I remove below code from above class, then class work correctly.

```
private FilterInfo<T> info;
```

but FilterInfo has all prerequisite for use(Serializable, T extends Serializable, default Constructor)

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class FilterInfo<T extends Serializable> implements Serializable {
private String name;
private Class<?> type;

public FilterInfo() { }
public FilterInfo(String name, Class<?> type) {
    setName(name);  setType(type.getClass());
}

public String getName() { return name; }
...
```

Answer (score 2):

`Class<?>` is not serializable by GWT, therefore neither is `FilterInfo`, and therefor neither is `Filter`. Consider that the compiler would need to leave in all possible class literals that are reachable by the compiler, in order to support this.

Instead, either find a different way to describe the `type` data, or build a CustomFieldSerialize for `FilterInfo` which can read from the stream and figure out which Class to use as a type, if there is a simple list you support, or an easy way to make a registry.